# Why do I get "ImportError: No module named" when I try to run my Python script via the Interpreter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation

I am relatively new to Python and already developing automation framework in my company.

For the first time, during the development process, I got into a situation that I need to run several tests simultaneously. Till this point I always used Eclipse, not only to develop my framework but also run tests (of course it is only one at a time).
When I tried to run one of my tests (one that I managed to run through Eclipse) through the CMD screen "python " it didn't even start running and the result that I got was "ImportError: No module named" (relates to the imports that I do from packages that I developed).

How does Eclipse manage to get along with all my Imports and run my tests, while the python interpreter couldn't ?

What do i need to do in order to manage to run my tests via the interpreter ?

**Edit**

The following are examples to what I tried in order to import my proprietary modules

```
 C:\Users\alpha_2.PL\workspace\PacketLight Automation\Test_Cases>python
 Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900
 64 bit (AM D64)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or
 "license" for more information.
 >>> from Utilities.Browser_Utils import Open_Browser Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ImportError:
 No module named 'Utilities'
 >>> quit()

 C:\Users\alpha_2.PL\workspace\PacketLight Automation\Test_Cases>cd..

 C:\Users\alpha_2.PL\workspace\PacketLight Automation>cd Utilities

 C:\Users\alpha_2.PL\workspace\PacketLight Automation\Utilities>python
 Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900
 64 bit (AM D64)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or
 "license" for more information.
 >>> from Utilities.Browser_Utils import Open_Browser Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ImportError:
 No module named 'Utilities'
 >>> quit()

 C:\Users\alpha_2.PL\workspace\PacketLight Automation\Utilities>dir 
 Volume in drive C has no label.  Volume Serial Number is 1E0C-6554

  Directory of C:\Users\alpha_2.PL\workspace\PacketLight Automation\Utilities

 08/07/2017  03:05 PM    <DIR>          .
 08/07/2017  03:05 PM    <DIR>          ..
 08/10/2017  10:28 AM               455 Browser_Utils.py 
 09/05/2017  05:00 PM             7,007 General_Utils.py
 07/31/2017  01:49 PM                 0 __init__.py
 09/05/2017  06:07 PM    <DIR>          __pycache__
                3 File(s)          7,462 bytes
                3 Dir(s)  394,707,480,576 bytes free

 C:\Users\alpha_2.PL\workspace\PacketLight Automation\Utilities>python
 Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900
 64 bit (AM D64)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or
 "license" for more information.
 >>> from Utilities.Browser_Utils import Open_Browser 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ImportError:
 No module named 'Utilities'
 >>>
```

Comment: use python3 instead of python in your command. Else you have to use pip3 to install all python3 package.

Comment: It look like you need to do a little reading about the Python environment - hardly nusual in someone who's learned to use the language with an IDE. You will probably find that Eclipse makes special efforts to manage the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Comment: @rabbit_mq what is python3 ? And why do you think that it can solve my problem ?

Comment: @holdenweb I did my best to better understand the Python environment before I started utilizing it for my use. I know some details about sys.path and I know that my problem relates somehow to this file. But, from this point to know practically how to fix this.. there is a distance. Do you know what should I do in order to solve this issue ?

Comment: most system have default python 2 not 3 .

Comment: I am working with Python 3.5.x but I get this result when I tried to run python3 " 'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: There is no python3.exe file, that is why it fails. Probably py -3 will work.

Comment: If you are sure you have installed Python, you should adjust your shell's `PATH` to include the directory where the Python executable lives. Lots of good advice at https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/windows.html

Comment: My python interpreter runs very well. I even manage to import all the builtin modules. But, when it comes to my project I have a problem. I understand the reason for the error message, the interpreter isn't familiar with the packages that I wrote. My question is how do I set the sys.path in a way that all the imported modules (those modules which I wrote and are wrapped in packages) will be "known". What is the right way to do that ?

Comment: Investigate PYTHONPATH first. Then (for future peace of mind) learn about virtual environments. The essence is that elements of `PYTHONPATH` are prepended to `sys.path` at startup, so you can make sure the directory(ies) containing your code are available on `sys.path`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this issue. When some answers here pointed PYTHONPATH I misinterpreted it with the PATH (environment variables) and therefore didn't solve my problem by only editing sys.path.

When I realized that I need to create PYTHONPATH myself and add my own paths then I managed to import my packages.

Thanks for all the people who answered without you I didn't have any direction regarding the solution of this issue

Answer (score 2):

All I can imagine is that Eclipse would run your command from the project directory, which make relative imports work.

If I'm running python in /home/jpic, and foo.py exists there, then I can `import foo`. However, if i'm running python in /home, then `import foo` will fail. So, make sure you cd into the right directory before calling python.

If I wanted to make foo importable from everywhere, I would have to make it a python package, which might not be something you want to do with your project (but I would, with all my projects, because it's way cool to have imports working everywhere ^^).

If you want to debug imports, run `python` with `-vv`, you'll get import debug output as such:

```
# trying /home/jpic/foo.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
# trying /home/jpic/foo.abi3.so
# trying /home/jpic/foo.so
# trying /home/jpic/foo.py
# trying /home/jpic/foo.pyc
# trying /usr/lib/python3.6/foo.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
# trying /usr/lib/python3.6/foo.abi3.so
# trying /usr/lib/python3.6/foo.so
# trying /usr/lib/python3.6/foo.py
# trying /usr/lib/python3.6/foo.pyc
# trying /usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/foo.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
# trying /usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/foo.abi3.so
# trying /usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/foo.so
# trying /usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/foo.py
# trying /usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/foo.pyc
# trying /home/jpic/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/foo.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
# trying /home/jpic/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/foo.abi3.so
# trying /home/jpic/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/foo.so
# trying /home/jpic/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/foo.py
# trying /home/jpic/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/foo.pyc
# trying /home/jpic/src/django-cities-light/foo.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
# trying /home/jpic/src/django-cities-light/foo.abi3.so
# trying /home/jpic/src/django-cities-light/foo.so
# trying /home/jpic/src/django-cities-light/foo.py
# trying /home/jpic/src/django-cities-light/foo.pyc
# trying /home/jpic/src/django-autocomplete-light/src/foo.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
# trying /home/jpic/src/django-autocomplete-light/src/foo.abi3.so
# trying /home/jpic/src/django-autocomplete-light/src/foo.so
# trying /home/jpic/src/django-autocomplete-light/src/foo.py
# trying /home/jpic/src/django-autocomplete-light/src/foo.pyc
# trying /home/jpic/src/django-autocomplete-light/test_project/src/genericm2m/foo.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
# trying /home/jpic/src/django-autocomplete-light/test_project/src/genericm2m/foo.abi3.so
# trying /home/jpic/src/django-autocomplete-light/test_project/src/genericm2m/foo.so
# trying /home/jpic/src/django-autocomplete-light/test_project/src/genericm2m/foo.py
# trying /home/jpic/src/django-autocomplete-light/test_project/src/genericm2m/foo.pyc
# trying /home/jpic/work/mez/src/foo.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
# trying /home/jpic/work/mez/src/foo.abi3.so
# trying /home/jpic/work/mez/src/foo.so
# trying /home/jpic/work/mez/src/foo.py
# trying /home/jpic/work/mez/src/foo.pyc
# trying /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/foo.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
# trying /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/foo.abi3.so
# trying /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/foo.so
# trying /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/foo.py
# trying /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/foo.pyc
# trying /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0/foo.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
# trying /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0/foo.abi3.so
# trying /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0/foo.so
# trying /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0/foo.py
# trying /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0/foo.pyc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'
```

Note that the above debug output is made on standard error, not standard input. This means that you should use `&>` instead of `>` to redirect it to a file, on bash4, or `2>` on windows *i think*, after reading [their docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/110930/redirecting-error-messages-from-command-prompt-stderr-stdout).

I don't know eclipse so I'm unable to talk about what it does, but this trick should give you sufficient feedback from the interpreter to hack your own solution.

Another possibility is that Eclipse uses Python3 and you are using Python2 in the CLI. In this case, you would need to add `__init__.py` files in your module directories, or rather, make sure your CLI is python 3, check with `python --version`. Example:

```
07/09 2017 12:03:11 jpic@mez /tmp 
$ mkdir foo

07/09 2017 12:03:13 jpic@mez /tmp 
$ touch foo/bar.py

07/09 2017 12:03:16 jpic@mez /tmp 
$ python3
Python 3.6.2 (default, Jul 20 2017, 03:52:27) 
[GCC 7.1.1 20170630] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import foo.bar
>>> 

07/09 2017 12:03:20 jpic@mez /tmp 
$ python2
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jul 21 2017, 03:24:34) 
[GCC 7.1.1 20170630] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import foo.bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named foo.bar
>>> 

07/09 2017 12:03:28 jpic@mez /tmp 
$ touch foo/__init__.py

07/09 2017 12:03:33 jpic@mez /tmp 
$ python2
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jul 21 2017, 03:24:34) 
[GCC 7.1.1 20170630] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import foo.bar
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but failed to print out the result to a file with ">". So, I can't really use it to debug because the list was longer than the CMD buffer size,. By the way, I have already started my debug with "print(sys.path)" and I revealed which Paths are included. Correct me if I'm wrong but I understand that if my path isn't found there than there is no reason for Python to be able to interpret the proprietary modules that I import

Comment: This is because it is outputed to standard error, and not standard output. If on bash 4 , try `&>` instead of `>`. Also, sys.path starts with an empty string here `['', ...]`, which I suppose represents the current working directory, which I'm talking about at the beginning of my answer, did you get that ?

Comment: By the way, after doing the above I tried to copy all my Project (with all its packages) to one of the Paths that are found in sys.path and then tried to run one of my scripts. This also resulted with "ImportError: No module named"

Comment: I'm running under windows CMD screen

Comment: As it was commented on your question, perhaps eclipse is running python3 and you are running python2 on the CLI. The main difference being that in python2, module directories need a file named `__init__.py` to be recognized, that's not the case in python3.

Comment: I'm actually running python 3

Comment: On windows, see this for stderr redirect: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/110930/redirecting-error-messages-from-command-prompt-stderr-stdout

Comment: Then the current working directory is the only explanation I can think of, that would break relative imports outside of Eclipse. Make sure you cd into the same directory eclipse is before you run your python command.

Comment: First of all thanks for the redirect answer. I managed to print the results to a text file but what i can only see is that python tried to import one of my modules from all the existing .py files. Regarding the path, I have only tried to run the the .py file from the same path it is found in. The imported modules are found in two other folders but not under the same path the the .py files is found

Comment: My project is consisted out of 3 Packages (each already includes __init__.py files. I have one Package which is called Test_Cases. This one includes the script files. and the two other Packages include several modules (these are the modules that I import in my scripts)

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on your IDE to make modules importable.

When using virtual environments (or, at your own peril, using `sudo` to install in the system Python), it's easy to install correctly-packaged software using the `pip` utility.

Until you learn how to do those, note that the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable should be a semicolon-(Windows) or colon-(Unix) separated list of directories, each of which is prepended to `sys.path` at interpreter startup time. You can therefore ensure that your software, even if not `pip`-installable, can be made available for use.

Comment: I added the Utilities Package (from the example above) path to the sys.path (by using "sys.path.append()") and still I get the same error when I try to run a "from Utilities.Browser_Utils import Open_Browser". What could be the problem ?

Comment: I'd try to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this issue. In the course of formulating it, you might find out what you are doing wrong.

Comment: If I would say that I want to start from the beginning. After I install Python the next step would be writing the new packages and modules. In this case where would I need to place my packages in order to not need to touch sys.path at all ? And what if I wanted to create my packages and put them where ever I would like. where would i put my packages then and what would I need to write into sys.path ?

Comment: There's a utility called `pip` that installs third-party packages in Python's _.../site-packages_ directory. If you want to install packages in your system's Python (which I do NOT recommend) you will need to use `sudo`. If you learn to use virtual environments you can install into those without `sudo`, and have several that you switch between.